# How to Install mongodb on fedora 23

Tags: mongodb

[image]

my system configuration is based on the attached image file.please help me out to install orelse I need to write a entire configuration ??

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried and the errors that you are getting. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/ i tried the steps which they mentioned in the link

Comment: Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf install -y mongodb-org'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run:
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'

Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'sublime2', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'influxdb', disabling.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mongodb-org-3.2', disabling.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:29:51 ago on Mon May  9 13:03:41 2016.
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Unable to find a match.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.2.repo file so that you can
>      install MongoDB directly, using yum. Use the following repository file:
>
>    [mongodb-org-3.2]
>      name=MongoDB Repository
>      baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
>      gpgcheck=1
>      enabled=1
>      gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc
> 2. `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org`

Reference: [MongoDB Docs for Installing mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#configure-the-package-management-system-yum)

Comment: how long it will take to create a repo file...its running a long time.. vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.2.repo

Comment: it shouldn't take long it is a simple process u should use sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.2.repo

Comment: yup i had been tried under root user only ....now mongodb running on my system by simply running a mongo and mongod in terminal .1) open a terminal upto bin and run mongo and mongodb in separate terminal window (be sure we have to under root user)..thanx to all for the support

Comment: @rummykhan I am following official documentation (same .repo config as you mentioned) but I still get an error message: `Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'mongodb-org-3.2'`

Comment: @Athlan I had the same problem.  Apparently the variable $releasever is different for Fedora (e.g. 23).  This variable should be the Redhat version.  So replace the variable with '7' (the current Redhat version), and it should work.  (At least, it worked on my machine!)